# Does sequence always give a square

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Show that there exist a non-constant postive integer sequence $\{a_{n}\},a_{0}=1$ such that 
$$\dfrac{a^2_{n}+a_{n}}{2}-\dfrac{a^2_{n-1}+a_{n-1}}{2},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ is always a perfect square.

Comment: What does $a_0$ equal?

Comment: a sequence of all zeros satisfy your condition.

Comment: @Daga The OP asked for a positive integer sequence.

Comment: How do you know that such a sequence exists? What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Well, a sequence of all 1s will do it.

Comment: $a_n = a > 0$ any constant?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of flagging the post as unclear?

Comment: Well, $a_n^2 + a_n/2 = \sum_{a_n} i$ so we need $\sum_{i= a_{n-1}+1}^{a_n} i = m^2$

Comment: a_1 = 1, a_2 = 4, a_3 = 13.... don't know what a_4 is yet.

Comment: The initial typing and wording was difficult and unclear but this should certainly *not* have been voted as off-topic.  The question, once the trivial answers were cleared away, was very mathematical and precise and quite challenging and illuminating.  I definitely think this should be opened.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=\frac{3^n-1}2$ (so indeed $a_1=\frac{3^1-1}2=1$). Then
$$ \frac{a_n^2+a_n}2-\frac{a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-1}}2=\frac{3^{2n}-1}8-\frac{3^{2(n-1)}-1}8=3^{2(n-1)}=(3^{n-1})^2.$$

Comment: Hmm, that's the same answer I got.  But I didn't apply recursion to get the actual formula.

Answer (score 1):

$a_1 = 1$

$a_n = 3a_n + 1$.

[edit add] as per Hagen von Eitzen' answer: $a_n = (3^n -1)/2$

$a_1 = 1; 3a_{n -1} + 1 = 3(3^{n-1} - 1)/2 + 1 = (3^n -3)/2 + 1 = (3^n -1)/2$

[/edit add]

{1, 4, 13, 40,...}

Because

$(a_n^2 + a_n)/2 = \sum_{i=1}^{a_n} i$

So $(a_n^2 + a_n)/2 - (a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n-1})/2 = \sum_{i = a_{n-1}+1}^{a_n}i = (a_{n-1} + a_n + 1)/2 *(a_n - a_{n-1})$

If $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 1$ then $a_n - a_{n-1} = (a_{n-1} + a_n + 1)/2$ so difference is a perfect square.